# Google Maps zoomOut-Pan-zoomIn animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, settimeout

I'm wondering how I get a smooth zoom in animation with the Google Maps API.

I have 2 points, one in, let say China, and one in France. When I'm zoomed in on China, and click the button France. I want it to gradually zoom out smooth, one zoom level at the time. When it's zoomed out it should pan to the new location, and then zoom in on the new location one zoom level at the time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need the [`zoomOut`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.zoomOut) method with the continuous zoom parameter set to do the zoom and the [`panTo`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.panTo) method to do the smooth panning to the new centerpoint.

You can listen to the [`zoomEnd`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.zoomend) and [`moveEnd`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.moveend) events on the map object to chain together your `zoomOut`, `panTo` and `zoomIn` methods.

EDIT:

So in the course of implementing a sample for this problem,  I discovered that the `doContinuousZoom` param on `ZoomIn` and `ZoomOut` (or just `EnableContinuousZoom` on the map) doesn't quite work as expected.  It works ok when zooming out, if the tiles are in the cache (this is an important point, if the tiles aren't cached then it is not really possible to get the smooth animation you are after) then it does some nice scaling on the tiles to simulate a smooth zoom animation and introduces a ~500 ms delay on each zoom step so you can do it asynchronously (unlike `panTo`, which you will see in my example I use a setTimeout to call async).

Unfortunately the same is not true for the `zoomIn` method, which just jumps to the target zoom level without the scaling animation for each zoom level.  I haven't tried explicitly setting the version for the google maps code, so this might be something that is fixed in later versions.  Anyway, here is the [sample code](http://www.cannonade.net/geo2.js) which is mostly just javascript hoop jumping and not so much with the Google Maps API:

http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo2

Because this approach seems a bit unreliable, I think it would make more sense to do the async processing for setZoom explicitly (Same as the panning stuff).

EDIT2:

So I do the async zooming explicitly now (using `setTimeout` with a single zoom at a time).  I also have to fire events when each zoom happens so that my events chain correctly.  It seems like the zoomEnd and panEnd events are being called synchronously.

Setting enableContinuousZoom on the map doesn't seem to work, so I guess calling zoomOut, zoomIn with the param is the only way to get that to work.

Comment: I knew I had to do something like that, what I'm wondering is how I exactly I would do it?

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it ;)

Comment: I have updated my example to use setTimout and it seems much smoother now (at least on the zoom out).

Comment: So were you able to get the smooth zoom happening ?

Comment: Anyone find this for v3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API?

Answer (score 5):

Here's my approach.

```
var point = markers[id].getPosition(); // Get marker position
map.setZoom(9); // Back to default zoom
map.panTo(point); // Pan map to that position
setTimeout("map.setZoom(14)",1000); // Zoom in after 1 sec
```

Comment: This is a very jerky solution.  I would not recommend it.  I did it this week and it was not presentable enough.  Even the pan to is too fast and linear and so I wrote s script that slowed it down and made it exponential in deceleration.
i would go with RedBlueThing's solution.

Comment: exponential is definitely much better in this method, but still not good enough. I feel it needs to be doing panning and zooming at the same time to look real smooth...I don't know how though

Comment: This isn't good. Takes too much time, plus any animation or movement should be under 600ms or else your wasting the users time!

Answer (score 3):

```
var zoomFluid, zoomCoords;   //shared variables

function plotMarker(pos, name){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title:name,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: pos
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            zoomCoords = marker.getPosition();     //Updates shared position var
            zoomFluid = map.getZoom();            //Updates shared zoom var;
            map.panTo(zoomCoords);       //initial pan
            zoomTo();                   //recursive call
    });

}

//  increases zoomFluid value at 1/2  second intervals
function zoomTo(){
    //console.log(zoomFluid);
    if(zoomFluid==10) return 0;
    else {
         zoomFluid ++;
         map.setZoom(zoomFluid);
         setTimeout("zoomTo()", 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the zoom this one worked for me nicely:

```
function animateMapZoomTo(map, targetZoom) {
    var currentZoom = arguments[2] || map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoom != targetZoom) {
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function (event) {
            animateMapZoomTo(map, targetZoom, currentZoom + (targetZoom > currentZoom ? 1 : -1));
        });
        setTimeout(function(){ map.setZoom(currentZoom) }, 80);
    }
}
```